# Number of derangements where first m numbers are fixed points

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let $m,n \in \mathbb N$ with $m<n$. Find, in terms of $D_{k}$'s the number of derangements $a_{1},a_{2},...a_{n}$ of $\mathbb N_{n}$ such that {$a_{1},a_{2},...a_{m}$} = {$1,2,...,m$}.

My thoughts:

1) The number of derangements of $\mathbb N_{n} $ is $D_{n}$.

2) The first m numbers of N are fixed points. So the number of n-permutations of $\mathbb N_{n}$ with m fixed points is $D(n,n,m)$

The answer given is $D_{m}D_{n-m}$

EDIT:
Definition of r-permutation of n elements with k fixed points, denoted by D(n,r,k) in the text.

A = {1,2,3,4}

D(4,3,3) - The number of 3 permutations with 3 fixed points is 1. 123.

D(4,3,2) - The number of 3 permutations with 2 fixed points is 3. 124,143,423

Comment: Do you mean that $m$ of the elements are deranged among themselves? A derangement, by definition, cannot have fixed points.

Comment: You have to derange $m$ objects among themselves, then $n-m$ objects among themselves. There is not much to prove here.

Comment: I saw this definition in my text. Let $D(n,r,k)$ denote the number of r-permutations of $\mathbb N_{n}$ that have exactly k fixed points.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I don't see clearly why you have to multiply them together? Can you clarify it further pls. :)

Comment: @Nishant I realized the question doesn't make much sense too. How can $a_{1},a_{2},...a_{n}$ be deranged if it's first m numbers are not deranged? Is there any other perspective to the question?

Comment: What's an $r$-permutation?

Comment: @Nishant r-permutation is permutating r elements out of the n elements

Comment: Okay, so what does it mean for the $r$ permutation to have $k$ fixed points? Do the $k$ fixed points have to be a subset of the $r$ elements being permuted?

Comment: @Nishant Kindly see my edit above

Comment: It's not that the first $m$ numbers are fixed points, rather the *set* of the first $m$ numbers is invariant under the permutation, that is for $1 \leq i \leq m$, we have $1 \leq \pi(i) \leq m$. In other words, $\pi$ maps $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $[k] = \{1,\ldots,k\}$. If a permutation $\pi$ of $[n]$ satisfies $\pi([m]) = [m]$ then it also satisfies $\pi([n]\setminus [m]) = [n]\setminus [m]$, so $\pi|_{[m]}$ is a permutation of $[m]$ and $\pi|_{[n]\setminus[m]}$ is a permutation of $[n]\setminus[m]$. Furthermore, it is a derangement if any only if $\pi|_{[m]}$ and $\pi|_{[n] \setminus [m]}$ are both derangements. There are $D_m$ possibilities for the former and $D_{n-m}$ for the latter.

Comment: Still quite confused.. =) What does the notation $\pi|_{[m]}$ mean?

Comment: What does the notation $\pi|_{[m]}$ mean vs the notation $\pi{([m])}$?

Comment: Here $\pi|_{[m]}$ is the restriction of $\pi$ to $[m]$, while $\pi([m])$ is the image of $[m]$ under $\pi$.

Comment: What does restriction of $\pi$ to $[m]$ mean exactly? For example, the image of A = {1,2,3,4} under $\pi$ is for example {3,4,1,2} right?

Comment: I don't know what $\pi$ is so I can't really say. The restriction of $\pi$ to $[m]$ is the function defined on $[m]$ given by $x \mapsto \pi(x)$. For example, if $\pi$ is the identity permutation on $\{1,2,3,4\}$, then $\pi$ restricted to $\{1,2\}$ is the identity permutation on $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: If $\pi$ is the identity permutation on {1,2,3,4}, then the image of A = {1,2,3,4} under $\pi$ is {1,2,3,4} and the restriction basically means any subset of A?

Comment: No, the restriction of a function is another function defined on a (possibly) smaller domain. For example, the permutation $\pi(1)=2$, $\pi(2) = 3$, $\pi(3) = 1$ on $\{1,2,3\}$ has the restriction $\psi = \pi|_{\{1,2\}}$ given by $\psi(1) = 2$, $\psi(2) = 3$, which is *not* a permutation since $\pi(\{1,2\}) = \{2,3\} \neq \{1,2\}$.

Comment: Is $\pi(1)$ a permutation of the element 1 in the set {1,2,3}? Why is the number of permutations 2? Sorry, it's getting clearer but at the same time, I'm getting stuck with the mathematical notations.

Comment: Will get back after a few hours, thanks a lot!

Comment: A permutation is a bijection from some set $S$ to itself. In particular, $\pi(1)$ is not a permutation, since $\pi(1)$ is just a number. If $|S|$ is finite then there are $|S|!$ permutations of $S$.

Comment: Then why is $\pi(1)$ 2?

Comment: $\pi(1) = 2$ since the value of the function $\pi$ at the point $1$ is $2$. That doesn't make $\pi(1)$ a permutation, since $2$ is a number rather than a function.

Comment: If you are interested, here's my another unanswered question.. :) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946309/numbers-fulfilling-a-certain-condition-in-a-range-of-numbers

Comment: I think I'll understand this much better if I see an example of such a derangement. Let's say $m = 3$,$n=5$. Can you give me a permutation which is a derangement satisfying the above condition? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. In fact, here are all of them: 23154, 31254.

Comment: Hmm, I think I still don't see how it satisfies the condition $a_{1},a_{2},...a_{n}$ of $\mathbb N_{n}$. When n=5, $a_1=1$,$a_2=2$,$a_3=3$,$a_4=4$ and $a_5=5$ right? If this is the case, then in the permutation 23154, $a_1$ is not 1 and $a_2$ is not 2 right?

Comment: The condition is $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\} = \{1,2,3\}$, rather than what you wrote.